# npm flatmap-stream@0.1.1 not found

Tags: angular, heroku, npm, npm-install

I have this error below but I dont have this package on my projecto directly. Anyone else is experiencing the same error? The project compiles and run correctly on my local env and I only get this error when i'm uploading the code to my heroku server. Yesterday I hade the same error with event-stream@3.3.6 but I deleted node_modules folder, deleted package-lock.json and run npm install and everything worked.

> npm ERR! 404 Not Found: flatmap-stream@0.1.1

```
            {
                "name": "myproj",
                "version": "0.0.0",
                "scripts": {
                    "ng": "ng",
                    "build": "ng build",
                    "start": "node server.js",
                    "test": "ng test",
                    "lint": "ng lint",
                    "e2e": "ng e2e",
                    "postinstall": "ng build --aot --prod"
                },
                "private": true,
                "dependencies": {
                    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
                    "@agm/js-marker-clusterer": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
                    "@agm/snazzy-info-window": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
                    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.0",
                    "@angular/cli": "^7.0.5",
                    "@angular/common": "^6.1.0",
                    "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.0",
                    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.0",
                    "@angular/core": "^6.1.0",
                    "@angular/elements": "^6.1.10",
                    "@angular/forms": "^6.1.0",
                    "@angular/http": "^6.1.0",
                    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.0",
                    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.0",
                    "@angular/router": "^6.1.0",
                    "@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet": "^4.0.0",
                    "@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet-markercluster": "^1.0.0",
                    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^2.0.0",
                    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.5.0",
                    "@hackages/ngxerrors": "^6.0.3",
                    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^3.3.1",
                    "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.0",
                    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
                    "@types/leaflet": "^1.2.13",
                    "@types/leaflet.markercluster": "^1.0.3",
                    "@ultimate/ngxerrors": "^1.4.0",
                    "@webcomponents/custom-elements": "^1.2.1",
                    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
                    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
                    "document-register-element": "^1.7.2",
                    "express": "^4.16.4",
                    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
                    "js-marker-clusterer": "^1.0.0",
                    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
                    "leaflet": "^1.3.4",
                    "leaflet.markercluster": "^1.4.1",
                    "ng4-loading-spinner": "^1.2.3",
                    "ngx-toastr": "^9.1.1",
                    "ngx-toggle": "^2.0.1",
                    "ngx-ui-switch": "^8.0.0-beta.0",
                    "rxjs": "^6.2.2",
                    "save": "^2.3.2",
                    "snazzy-info-window": "^1.1.1",
                    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
                },
                "devDependencies": {
                    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.8.0",
                    "@angular/cli": "^7.0.5",
                    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.0",
                    "@angular/language-service": "^6.1.0",
                    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
                    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
                    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
                    "codelyzer": "~4.3.0",
                    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
                    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
                    "karma": "~3.0.0",
                    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
                    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
                    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
                    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
                    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
                    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
                    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
                    "typescript": "~2.9.2"
                },
                "engines": {
                    "node": "~8.12.0",
                    "npm": "~6.4.1"
                }
            }
```

Comment: This package was injected with a malware/backdoor. Maybe it was deleted ? https://github.com/dominictarr/event-stream/issues/115

Comment: @ArturSmolen But I dont use it directly, how do I solve this now?

Comment: Dont really know... I found this which could be usefull: https://www.reddit.com/r/npm/comments/a2c53k/help_how_to_replace_eventstream_package_in/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the other answers don't work for you do the following.

- Check if you still have node_modules folders, if you don't do `yarn install`
- do `yarn audit`
- You'll find the modules which are trying to install flatmap-steam
- You have to either replace those modules with relevant modules or upgrade the versions of those modules. In my case it was gulp-angular-templatecache.

Then I recommend you to do a yarn install again. The project should work now.

Note: `npm audit` might not work if you are using a private repository, but yarn audit works.

Comment: "flatmap-stream" might be added to the project because of a dependency which is also might be a dependency.

Answer (score 10):

you just need to remove the following lines of code from your following file

- package.lock.json

==> "flatmap-stream": "0.1.1"
and 
==>
    "flatmap-stream": {
      "version": "0.1.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/flatmap-stream/-/flatmap-stream-0.1.1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-lAq4tLbm3sidmdCN8G3ExaxH7cUCtP5mgDvrYowsx84dcYkJJ4I28N7gkxA6+YlSXzaGLJYIDEi9WGfXzMiXdw=="
    }

basically,node team has removed that module because it had some malicious code.

Comment: i have removed the above code from  package.lock.json file, but still getting the error.

Answer (score 8):

> This is not a solution but a **WARNING**

**You should not use this package**. Thats a malicious package that has been added as a dependency package to another one which name is `event-stream`. `flatmap-stream` is meant to steal your `bitcoins` or any cryptocurrency informations. Check this [out](https://snyk.io/blog/malicious-code-found-in-npm-package-event-stream/). Check this [one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flatmap-stream) also. As suggested previously you have to jump into.

To keep working follow **SuperUser Sudo** solution. Remove the package from your `.lock` file and install it again.

Comment: A. This package can't be used anymore, it's gone.
B. It specifically only works on a single node application.

Answer (score 4):

To identify which is the package affected by the attack:

```
npm ls event-stream flatmap-stream
```

Since the package was dropped, you need to update your dependency or change it to another library.

In my case was the `nodemon` that was using `ps-tree` that was using `event-stream`.
I just had to update the `nodemon`, because the maintainers updated the source code, now it is no longer using `ps-tree`.

Comment: @John you can see more about the discussion at the oficial repository: https://github.com/dominictarr/event-stream/issues/116

Comment: Thank you, my problem was hammerjs

Answer (score 1):

I removed the `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` . Then run the following command solved the problem

```
npm install
```